# Pandas : Fill rows and drop duplicates, but keep different values

Tags: python, pandas

I'll try to be as clear as possible with my example.

```
df_old

user, col1,col2,col3
a   ,  X  ,    ,
a   ,     ,  Y ,
a   ,     ,    , 6
b   ,  A  ,    ,
b   ,     ,  B , C
b   ,     ,  D ,
```

This dataframe is ordered by `user`. I would like to fill the blanks and drop the duplicates, so for user a I would get only one row in the final dataframe.
I'm struggling with cases like user b. As there are 2 different values in col2 for user b, I want the final dataframe to have 2 different rows :

```
df_new

user, col1,col2,col3
a   ,  X  ,  Y , 6
b   ,  A  ,  B , C
b   ,  A  ,  D , C
```

Note that I want the rows to be "consistent" so B and C stay at the same index.

Thanks a lot for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with set `NaNs` to duplicates by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), sorting by non NaNs values with forward missing values and last remove duplicates per groups `user`s:

```
out = (df.set_index('user')
         .groupby('user')
         .transform(lambda x: x.mask(x.duplicated()).sort_values(key=pd.isna).ffill())
         .reset_index()
         .drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True)
         )
print (out)
  user col1 col2 col3
0    a    X    Y    6
1    b    A    B    C
2    b    A    D    C
```

EDIT: If need missing values per rows if exist at least one non missing value omit `ffill` and add [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `axis='all'` parameter

```
out = (df.set_index('user')
         .groupby('user')
         .transform(lambda x: x.mask(x.duplicated()).sort_values(key=pd.isna))
         .dropna(how='all')
         .reset_index()
         )
print (out)
  user col1 col2 col3
0    a    X    Y    6
1    b    A    B    C
2    b  NaN    D  NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer !
How would I do to not fill the NaN values ? Row2 would be ```b,NaN,D,NaN```

Comment: @Movilla - Solution was added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.groupby('user', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.ffill()).dropna(how='any')
```

Output:

```
  user col1 col2 col3
2    a    X    Y    6
4    b    A    B    C
5    b    A    D    C
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to fill the NaNs, you could use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to shift the non-NaN values up, then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) the all-NaN rows:

```
out = (df.set_index('user')
         .groupby(level=0)
         .transform(lambda s: s.sort_values(key=lambda x: x.isna(),
                                            kind='stable').values)
         .dropna(how='all').reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
  user col1 col2 col3
0    a    X    Y    6
1    b    A    B    C
2    b  NaN    D  NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
                  'col1': ['X', None, None, 'A', None, None],
                  'col2': [None, 'Y', None, None, 'B', 'D'],
                  'col3': [None, None, '6', None, 'C', None]})
```

Comment: Perfect solution for my initial pb thanks. However the second suggestion to not fill the NaN values does not work for me :(

Comment: @Movilla can you provide details on how this doesn't work? Please provide a [mre] as DataFrame constructor and your pandas version.